# How to show percentage from a text row

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have my company core values like for example hardwork, ambitious, trust and courage. Daily i have to transcript the core value i have lived in excel sheet and prepare a percentage/pie chart for presentation.

I am trying with Pivot Chart so its coming like this way.[image: sheet] 
How do i make this in a pie chart where i can show the percentage of which core value i have lived in a calendar month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have to solve 2 problems at once.
You have to "unify" your starting attributes (no typos and if using two always the same sequence and the same sepeator). Then you need two columns. One for the core value/s (=data to analyse) the second for the description text.
Now you can analyse and count the occurence of each value in a kind of summary row. If you would use only 1 core value its number of core values counted per value divided by total num of counted values. If you use 2 values for a day its tricky I advise to use 2 data columns and you have to count 1 for one value/day or 0.5 if two/day (otherwise you get more than 100% or distorted values. The function you want to use is CountIF and CountIFS.

> The Excel COUNTIFS function returns the count of cells that meet one
>   or more criteria. COUNTIFS can be used with criteria based on dates,
>   numbers, text, and other conditions. COUNTIFS supports logical
>   operators (>,<,<>,=) and wildcards (*,?) for partial matching

The result values can then be brought in any grafic form suitable.

Comment: The CountIF is working as you said rightly there are two workarounds. Thanks.